# How to handle async API calls using redux-saga?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

Recently, we started using redux-saga middleware to manage our async API calls from the store.

Previously, we used the common promise based actions, which made it easy to manage components flow once we could use `async/await` and `.then()` and `.catch()` right on the action itself.

With promises:

```
const fetchCars = async () => {
  const {data} = await fetchCarsRequest();
  
  setCars(data);
}

cars.map((car) => <li>{car.name}</li>);
```

With sagas:

```
function* fetchCarsSaga() {
  try {
    const {data} = yield call(fetchCarsService);

    yield put(fetchCarsSuccess);
  } catch(error) {
    yield put(fetchCarsFailure);
  } 
}

const fetchCars = async () => {
 fetchCarsRequest(); //action that calls the above saga

 setCars(cars); //state from store 
}

cars.map((car) => <li>{car.name}</li>);
```

In the second example, even tough we use the generator to handle the async API call, it's not possible to use the `await` statement, so it calls the `setCars` function right after the `fetchCarsRequest` is called, trying to set to the component state something that does not exist yet.

So my question is: is there a way to replace the `await` statement for something and wait for the request function (that is not an async function) to finish the API call?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking - the fact that the names you use don't exactly match the function/generator names in your code don't help. But redux-saga's `call` will automatically "wait for" a Promise to resolve, if the called function returns a Promise - as all `async` functions do. If you put `await` before the call to `fetchCarsRequest` (so the promise implicitly returned by that function doesn't resolve until `fetchCarsRequest` does) then I think everything should work OK?

Comment: I guess couldn't express myself well enough. My main doubt is on how to wait for the API call to finish to call another function without using `await`, once the async call is being handled by the saga.

For instance, I wanna wait for the saga to finish the API call and set the state to the store, to open a success modal. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

using redux-saga, the flow would be a bit different. You don't use the generator directly in the component. You need to update the redux state from the saga and fetch it in the component.

```
react component -> redux action -> saga -> redux state -> react component
```

Two articles in PT-BR you could have a look at are:

- https://medium.com/nossa-coletividad/redux-saga-voc%C3%AA-no-controle-das-opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ass%C3%ADncronas-71c9e6b3aabc
- https://oieduardorabelo.medium.com/redux-saga-gerenciando-efeitos-f518a31c744e

And a good `create-react-app` template is:

- https://github.com/mmajdanski/cra-redux-saga-template

In CodeSandbox:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/6mgb2

Comment: Thank you, @oieduardorabelo, for your response. The articles are really useful. But my question is: how do I wait for the saga to finish the API call and set the state to the store, to only then open a success modal, for instance? In this case, the action the calls the saga would be called on a button click.

Comment: @GabrielSantana, you will need to control that within the redux state. Let's say your saga updates the redux state with `yield put({ type: "CAR_MODAL_OPEN" })`, this action triggers a reducer that returns and new state with `{ modals: { car: "open" } }`, then inside your react component, you can map this state to props, and in the render function you check for `props.carModal === 'open'` to render whatever you need. The cycle `react component -> redux action -> saga -> redux state -> react component` is how the state flows/updates.

Comment: Yeah. In fact, it does solve the problem. But it's still being handled inside the reducer, with a global state, and not inside the component that is calling the reducer. Maybe there's not a way to wait like `await` does. I guess with sagas you always have to keep tracking changes to the edux state to do something inside the `useEffect` based on the state value.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. you need to sync redux-saga and redux first, then you sync redux with react component, and later, you sync props with `useEffect`... not great, not terrible! hahaha good luck @GabrielSantana!

Answer (score 0):

#### Kill the Component State

You want to dispatch an action `fetchCarsRequest()` which triggers an API call and saves the results to your redux store.  You want to wait for this to finish, and then call `setCars(cars)` to set your component state to a value from the redux state.  Why?

This is an anti-pattern.  The data already exists in redux and should be accessed directly from redux in your component.  You should use `useSelector` or the `connect` HOC to select the value of `cars` from redux.  It will automatically re-render your component with the new data once your fetch has dispatched `fetchCarsSuccess` and updated the store state.

It should look something like this.

saga

```
function* fetchCarsSaga() {
  try {
    const {data} = yield call(fetchCarsService);

    // this action should store the data to the store
    // it needs the data as an argument!
    yield put(fetchCarsSuccess(data));
  } catch(error) {
    yield put(fetchCarsFailure(error));
  } 
}
```

component

```
const Cars = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const cars = useSelector( state => state.cars.data ) || [];
   const isLoading = useSelector( state => state.cars.isLoading );
   const error = useSelector( state => state.cars.error );

   useEffect( () => {
      dispatch(fetchCarsRequest()); // action that calls the saga
   }, [] );


   return (
      {!! error && (<div>Error: {error}</div>)}
      {isLoading ? <Spinner/> : (
        <ul>
          {cars.map((car) => <li key={car.id}>{car.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      )}
   )
}
```

Comment: @Gabriel In my opinion `useEffect` is the "right" way so I'm not sure why you want to do otherwise.  [tag:redux-thunk] middleware makes it so that you can `await` the `dispatch`.  I don't think redux-saga does the same but I've never tried it.

Comment: You guys are totally correct. It does solve the problem with the `useEffect`, but only in this context. In fact, I do this in almost every component that has to make an API request right at the begining, My question is: how do I wait for the saga to finish the API call and set the state to the store, to only then open a success modal, for instance? In this case, the request would be called on a button click.